# Regular Expression in Java for matching C 10 10 or L 1 2 6 2 or R 14 1 8 3

Tags: java, regex

I need help for creating a regular expression in Java to match my input from command prompt to any of these four formats only

```
C 10 10 
L 1 2 6 2 
R 14 1 8 3
Q
```

C can be followed by any two positive integers after space and having space between them.
L & R can be followed by four positive integers after space and having space in between them

Any thing other than these four is an error for my application.
So far I have achieved this

```
line.matches("[CLRQ]?\\s");
```

Comment: Can L be followed by 10 10, or is the pattern of digits that follow specific to the letter at the start of the line?

Comment: What do you mean `these four formats`?

Comment: C can be followed by any two positive integers after space and having space between them
L & R can be followed by four positive integers after space and having space in between them

Comment: Use [edit] option to clarify your question. Not many people will be willing to search for clarifications in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below regex:

```
C(?:\s\d+){2}|[LR](?:\s\d+){4}|Q
```

Desc:

```
C(?:\s\d+){2} - checks for literal character C followed by 2 digits
[LR](\s\d+){4} - checks for literal character L or R followed by 4 digits
Q - checks for character Q
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8Ro06s/2

Output:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-7 `C 10 10`
Match 2
Full match  9-18    `L 1 2 6 2`
Group 1.    16-18   ` 2`
Match 3
Full match  20-30   `R 14 1 8 3`
Group 1.    28-30   ` 3`
Match 4
Full match  31-32   `Q`
```

JShell Output:

```
jshell> Pattern patter = Pattern.compile("C(?:\\s\\d+){2}|[LR](\\s\\d+){4}|Q")
patter ==> C(?:\s\d+){2}|[LR](\s\d+){4}|Q
jshell> Matcher matcher = patter.matcher("C 10 10");
matcher ==> java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=C(?:\s\d+){2}|[LR ... }|Q region=0,7 lastmatch=]
jshell> matcher.matches()
$9 ==> true
jshell> Matcher matcher = patter.matcher("L 1 2 6 2");
matcher ==> java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=C(?:\s\d+){2}|[LR ... }|Q region=0,9 lastmatch=]
jshell> matcher.matches()
$11 ==> true
jshell> Matcher matcher = patter.matcher("R 14 1 8 3");
matcher ==> java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=C(?:\s\d+){2}|[LR ... |Q region=0,10 lastmatch=]
jshell> matcher.matches()
$14 ==> true
jshell> Matcher matcher = patter.matcher("Q");
matcher ==> java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=C(?:\s\d+){2}|[LR ... }|Q region=0,1 lastmatch=]
jshell> matcher.matches()
$15 ==> true
```